# How to design a good prompt to make openai upgrade json format flow

Tags: prompt, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a flow described in json format：

```
[
    {
        "id": "A1",
        "name": "input a city",
        "description": " A UI form accept city name",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"A2"
    },
    {
        "id": "A2",
        "name": "get the weather",
        "description": " get the weather of user's city",
        "nodeType":"Api Task",
        "next":"A3"

    },
    {
        "id": "A3",
        "name": "show the weather",
        "description": " Show the specific citiy's weather",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"none"

    }
]
```

Now we want to add step or delete step based on the flow using Natural Language,the classic question maybe as follow:

Human Question: After get the weather, use script to translate the temperature  to degrees Celsius.
The expected output is :

```
[
    {
        "id": "A1",
        "name": "input a city",
        "description": " A UI form accept city name",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"A2"
    },
    {
        "id": "A2",
        "name": "get the weather",
        "description": " get the weather of user's city",
        "nodeType":"Api Task",
        "next":"A4"

    },
    {
        "id": "A4",
        "name": "translate temperature",
        "description": " translate the temperature  to degrees Celsius",
        "nodeType":"Script Task",
        "next":"A3"

    },
    {
        "id": "A3",
        "name": "show the weather",
        "description": " Show the specific citiy's weather",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"none"
    }
]
```

So how to design the prompt?

This is my prompt, but it's not good:

```
You are a Intent analysis expert,Your task is to decompose user input into standard process steps in a specified format,Add, delete, or modify the <Current-Flow>.
Use the following `step-by-step` instructions to modify <Current-Flow> based on human query and return modified flow
1. If need add a process step, the process has the following types:
taskTypes: ["UI Task", "API Task", "Script Task"]
The process step format：
{
    "resourceId":"Serial numbers generated in sequence",
    "name":"name of node",
    "description":"description of node",
    "nodeType":"the task type in taskTypes",
    "next":"next nodeId in process",
}
2. If need delete a process step, just delete it
<Current-Flow>
[
    {
        "id": "A1",
        "name": "input a city",
        "description": " A UI form accept city name",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"A2"
    },
    {
        "id": "A2",
        "name": "get the weather",
        "description": " get the weather of user's city",
        "nodeType":"API Task",
        "next":"A3"

    },
    {
        "id": "A3",
        "name": "show the weather",
        "description": " Show the specific citiy's weather",
        "nodeType":"UI Task",
        "next":"none"

    }
]
</Current-Flow>

Human:
after get the weather, use script to translate the temperature  to degrees Celsius.

Copilot:
```